# Lip Reading classification on LiLiR dataset in matlab

Tags: matlab, svm

i work on lip reading but i am a newbie. 
after googling, i found that one of the data set of lip reading is LiLir dataset. now i downloaded it and i want to classify them using Support vector machine (SVM). but each letter has a matrix of data which has 4800 rows and 21 until 28 columns. i do not know what is the meaning of columns. they are features, but which features?

```
A1_Faye_lips = load('\data set\avletters\avletters\Lips\A1_Faye-lips.mat')

A1_Faye_lips = 

    vid: [4800x21 double]
    siz: [60 80 21]

>>
```

how can i train SVM using this 2D matrix?

Comment: I think you should read carefully the annotations about your dataset: http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/LILiR/twotalk_corpus/

Answer (score 0):

21 is the feature, I didn't look into the data source, so cannot tell what are those features exactly . But they are possibly the independent variables that influence the output (lip reading). Each variable is 4800*1 vector or 60*80 array.

For data training, [Libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/#matlab) is a good SVM training toolbox for you.